# yfinance - price scraping issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, yfinance

While scraping prices on 2 different dates, I am getting the same errros(although trading happened on the chose date) Anyone had similar issue, or maybe knows why the price is not being found?

No data found for AAPL on 2023-08-23

1 Failed download:
['AAPL']: Exception('%ticker%: No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1d 2023-08-23 -> 2023-08-23)')
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
No data found for TSLA on 2023-08-23

My function:

```
    starting_date = input("Enter a date to compare to (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
    sum_now = 0
    sum_then = 0
    error_stocks = []

    try:
        for ticker, quantity in portfolio.items():
            data = yf.download(ticker, start=starting_date, end=starting_date)
            if not data.empty:
                price_now = data['Close'].iloc[0]
                current_value = price_now * quantity
                sum_now += current_value
                sum_then += quantity * price_now
                print(f"{ticker}: {quantity} shares -> ${current_value:.2f}")
            else:
                error_stocks.append(ticker)
                print(f"No data found for {ticker} on {starting_date}")

        if error_stocks:
            print(f"Data not found for the following stocks: {', '.join(error_stocks)}")

        relative_gains = ((sum_now - sum_then) / sum_then) * 100 if sum_then != 0 else 0
        absolute_gains = sum_now - sum_then

        print(f'\nRelative Gains: {relative_gains:.2f}%')
        print(f'Absolute Gains: ${absolute_gains:.2f}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```